# Unexpected sorted list

Tags: java, list, lambda, comparator

Greeting,

I have 2 objects :

- Petition
- Signataire (signatory)

I wrote this code:

```
public List<Petition> getTheMostSigned(long groupId){

    List<Petition> petitionList = petitionPersistence.findByStatusAndGroupId(0,groupId);

    _log.info("list avant getTheMostSigned size  : "+petitionList.stream().map(petition -> petition.getSignataires().size()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    List<Petition> resultList = petitionList.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(petition -> petition.getSignataires().size()))
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    _log.info("list apres getTheMostSigned size  : "+resultList.stream().map(petition -> petition.getSignataires().size()).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return resultList;
```

The getSignataires() return a List.

but the result wasn't what I expected :

[image]

```
2018-09-12 12:44:25.686 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-10][PetitionLocalServiceImpl:390] list avant getTheMostSigned size  : [0, 0, 400, 0, 3, 401, 5501]
2018-09-12 12:44:25.856 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-10][PetitionLocalServiceImpl:396] list apres getTheMostSigned size  : [5501, 401, 3, 0, 0, **400**, 0]
```

As you can see, the penultimate is not the good one.
do you know why the Comparator isn't doing the job ?

Comment: Using `sorted()` twice is just wasteful.  The resulting order will be determined entirely by the latter of the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is expected as you chain two sorts.
The first one (`.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(petition -> petition.getSignataires().size())`) sorts by the list field size). **Then** the second one (`.sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())`) overwrites the first sort result as the last one sorts according to the reverse natural order of `Petition`.
As you invoke the sort stream operation twice, broadly it is like if you had used this logical :

```
List<Petition> petitionList = ...;
// first sort
petitionList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(petition -> petition.getSignataires().size());
// second sort
petitionList.sort(Collections.reversed());
```

What you need is defining a `Comparator` instance that combines these constraints.
And from Java 8, you can create `Comparator`s and combine them thanks essentially to `.thenComparingXXX()` and `.reversed()` methods.

So you could do :

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(petition -> petition.getSignataires().size())
                  .reversed()
       )
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need two `sorted` operations. They won't be combined to produce a  resulting `Comparator`.

The first constructs a `Comparator<Integer>` for `int size()` values, while the second **ignores the previous call** and applies its own `Comparator<Petition>` (`Comparator.<Petition>reverseOrder()`).

```
Comparator<Petition> reversedSignaturesSizeComparator 
        = Comparator.<Petition>comparingInt(p -> p.getSignataires().size()).reversed();
List<Petition> resultList = petitionList.stream()
                                        .sorted(reversedSignaturesSizeComparator)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is another way to do thing using Collection's other overloaded method which  uses custom compactor

```
Comparator<Petition> cmp = 
         (Petition left, Petition right) -> 
              left.getSignataires().size() - right.getSignataires().size();

List<Petition> resultList = petitionList.stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(cmp))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```